# my $_POST return null but my forms is not empty

Tags: php, mysql

i have two 3 files 1 for the database and the others is for add the data and the index but my
adddata.php doesn't catch the value and just return null

**connection.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
//general configs
$server = "Myserver";
$usuario = "MyuserName";
$senha = "Mypassword";
$banco = "MYdbname";
//Connection
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$banco", $usuario, $senha);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

**adddata.php**

```
<?php
require("db/connection.php");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    try {
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO clients (id,first_name,email,datinha) VALUES (default, first_name = :namess ,email = :emails , datinha = :datinha)");
        $sql->bindParam(":namess",$_POST["nome"]);
        $sql->bindParam(":emails",$_POST["mail"]);
        $sql->bindParam(":datinha",$_POST["datinha"]);
        $sql->execute();
        echo "Submitted" . PHP_EOL;
        header("Location: /crud/index.php?adicionou");
    }catch(PDOException $ex){
        echo "Something went wrong" . $ex->getMessage();
    }

}
```

**index.php**

```
    <div class="container">
        <form action="adddata.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="nome">
            <input type="email" name="mail">
            <input type="date" name="datinha">
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

PS: I'm using mysql and php 8.1

Comment: Where is the `action` parameter that submits your form to adddata.php? All you have there is a button that opens a page as a hyperlink - you need to submit the form using an appropriate button. Something like `<form method="post" action="adddata.php">` and `<input type="submit">`.

Comment: In `adddata.php`, you need to check whether the form has been submitted using `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")`

Comment: @droopsnoot thank you but now send a  null data for my database

Comment: @droopsnoot still send null using `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")`

Comment: Why do you have unquoted "default" in your database query? If `id` column is an autoincrement, you can set it to `null` or, better yet, just leave it out of the insert query. Also you are specifying column names in your SQL query, which is invalid syntax.

Comment: Valid insert queries would be either `INSERT INTO clients SET first_name = :namess, email = :emails, datinha = :datinha` or `INSERT INTO clients (first_name, email, datinha) VALUES (:namess, :emails, :datinha)` but not both together.

Comment: Where do you see NULL returned, `/crud/index.php`?

Answer (score 2):

Forms are submitted by **submit buttons**. You don't have one, your regular link is just a link.

Replace `<a class="btn-primary" href="adddata.php">Send</a>` with `<button>Send</button>`.

Add an `action` attribute to the `<form>` if you need to specify a URL to submit to that isn't the same as the current page's.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```html
<form method="post" action="adddata.php">
    <input type="text" name="nome">
    <input type="email" name="mail">
    <input type="date" name="datinha">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

The SQL looks a bit off, try this

```php
$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO clients (id, first_name, email, datinha) VALUES (default, :namess, :emails, :datinha)");
```

Comment: now send for my database empty data

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: i changed the name and forget to type CTRL + Z before try this but works thank you